# fix error Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-is'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ubuntu, pm2

I deployed an app on Ubuntu VPS. When I start the app using `pm2`, I got this error:

> Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-is' in '/root/apps/eduxxi-meeting/client/node_modules/styled-components/dist'

This is the `package.json` for my project:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8000",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "simple-peer": "^9.11.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.3.2",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts start",
    "build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I start the app like this:

```sh
pm2 start npm --name "eduxxi-meeting-ui" -- run start
```

What have I missed? I appreciate any help :)

Comment: Did you install the packages with 'npm install'?)

Comment: yes, I run npm install

Comment: ok, for some reason the module 'react-is', which is 'styled-components' dependency wasn't installed, perhaps you can try looking at the build/install logs

Comment: Looks like **react-is** is not added as a dependency in your package.json. did you also do a `npm install react-is`?

Comment: @Basile that was the problem, thankss